# Modifying a CC converter to act like a CV converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, constant-current, constant-voltage

I bought 3 DC/DC buck *constant current* converters instead of *constant voltage* converters (my intent was to power multiple servos with each one, and these were the only buck converters that fit the voltage / amperage demands of the servos).

I *cannot* return them.

Is there any way I can modify them to make them work in my situation?

**Basically my question is: can I modify my constant current converters to act like constant voltage converters?**

I couldn't find any module name so here is the [banggood link](https://m.banggood.com/en/Geekcreit-DC-6-40V-To-1_2-36V-300W-20A-Constant-Current-Adjustable-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-Board-p-1203369.html) where I bought them.[image]

This is one of my first projects and I am trying to make do with the mistakes I have made. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you have schematics? Reverse-engineered schematics are fine. It will probably be possible, but whether it's remotely worth doing is another matter.

Comment: The description of that product says it is a constant voltage converter.  Are you sure it doesn't already do what you need?

Comment: Wait ... that thing has a CV adjustment pot. Just put a small load on it (like 100R) and turn that pot until you get the right voltage,,,

Comment: It's probably a CV converter with an adjustable current limit set by the "CC" pot. On the bottom of the board it looks like there is an opamp wired to a current sense resistor so that would be the CC part. Can you post the reference of the big chip? The answer is probably in its datasheet. Also a clear pic of the bottom of the board...

Comment: I do not have schematics but I have edited the posts with a picture of the underside

Comment: You are right, there are 2 pots... Maybe i made a mistake thinking i made a mistake haha. Although i wonder : the servos have a big current draw (around .5A on standby up to 4A ) so what value do i set the CC pot to ?

Comment: Since you don't want to run in CC mode, set the CC limit to the maximum.  That puts you into CV mode.